# Class not visible

Tags: typescript, vite

I use Vite.js with typescript. I have a typescript file in 'src/vmodel/VGraph'.
In the index.html, I import the file like this:

```
 <script type="module" src="/src/vmodel/VGraph.ts"></script>
```

and then later:

```
  <script>
    const graph = new VGraph()
  </script>
```

with VGraph defined and declared `export` in file above.

I get the error message:
[image]

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: VGraph
```

What could be the reason for this?

The file seems to be loaded:
[image]

Comment: add screenshot of network tab in devtools with "js" only filter.

Comment: @bogdanoff: I added the screenshot. I believe the file is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are accessible only inside js module files so do this instead.

```js
// src/main.ts
import VGraph from './vmodel/VGraph.ts'
const graph = new VGraph()

//....
```

```html
<script type="module" src="./src/main.ts"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But then ...wouldn't main be yet another module that I cannot use from index.html?

Comment: yes, you can't. That's the purpose of modules.

Comment: interesting. So, what can I use from the Module in index.html? I tried to call a function of graph in index.html, but I couldn't. How do you interface? Where is this described?

Comment: why not call it  `main.ts` file, it same as calling it in `index.html`

Comment: are you facing race condition error ?, like trying to access DOM (in javascript) before html loads ?

Comment: I am not aware of main.ts. Is that a standard that I should use? What are the entry points to main.ts? BTW, thank you soo much!

Comment: its not standard but simply good practice, lets say if someone wants too look your code or you want to update this project after few years, they/you will look for staring point, if you don't have entrypoint you have look multiple files & that can start big head ache depending on no. of files you have.

Comment: if that graph code is large, move it to some other file & export a function that does graph stuff, then import it on main.ts & call that function.